# How To Get the XID of a Device

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

Via `xinput --list`, I'm able to get a list of all connected devices (pointers, keyboards, etc) with an attached `id`, however, I'm not certain how to go about getting the `XID` of these devices for use with a function call such as `XTestFakeDeviceMotionEvent`.

Comment: These ids are XIDs.

Comment: Ahh, so it is.  Thanks!